# Adding Strings into Object Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, object

I need help extracting the numbers from an input string " (Hussein Suleman, 02:40:010, 02:39:800") " and adding them into an Object Array. The output should ignore the bracets and print for eg Hussein Suleman [02:40:010, 02:39:800].

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Driver {

    private String name;
    private Time [] time;

    public Driver (String name, Time [] time)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public Driver (String dataLine) 
    {
        String str = dataLine.substring(1, dataLine.length() -1 );
        String [] data = str.split(",");
        name = data[0].trim();
        Time[]  time = new Time [data.length -1];

        for (int x = 1; x < data.length; x++)
        {
            time [x] = data[x].trim();
        }
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public Time [] getTime()
    {
        return time;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return name + " " + Arrays.deepToString(time);
    }

}
```

The Time Class is:

```
public class Time implements Comparable<Time> {


    private final int minutes;
    private final int seconds;
    private final int milliseconds;

    /**
     * Create a Time object representing the given period in minutes, seconds and milliseconds.
     */
    public Time(int minutes, int seconds, int milliseconds) {
        assert(0<=minutes&&minutes<60&&0<=seconds&&seconds<60&&0<=milliseconds&&milliseconds<=999);
        this.minutes=minutes;
        this.seconds=seconds;
        this.milliseconds=milliseconds;
    }

    /**
     * Create a Time object representing the given period in milliseconds.
     */
    public Time(int milliseconds) {
        this.milliseconds = milliseconds>0 ? milliseconds%1000 : 0;
        milliseconds = milliseconds/1000;
        this.seconds = milliseconds>=0 ? milliseconds%60 : 0;
        this.minutes = milliseconds/60;
    }

    /**
     * Create a Time object representing the given period in the form of a String representing
     * minutes, seconds, and milliseconds: "mm:ss:mmmm" e.g. "01:02:0341".
     */
    public Time(String string) {
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(string);
        scanner.useDelimiter(":");
        assert(scanner.hasNextInt());
        this.minutes = scanner.nextInt();
        assert(scanner.hasNextInt());
        this.seconds = scanner.nextInt();
        assert(scanner.hasNextInt());
        this.milliseconds = scanner.nextInt();
        assert(0<=minutes&&minutes<60&&0<=seconds&&seconds<60&&0<=milliseconds&&milliseconds<=999);
    }

    /**
     * Obtain the number of minutes.
     */
    public int getMinutes() { return this.minutes; }

    /**
     * Obtain the number of seconds.
     */
    public int getSeconds() { return this.seconds; }

    /**
     * Obtain the number of seconds.
     */
    public int getMilliseconds() { return this.milliseconds; }

    /**
     * Translate this Time object into a duration in milliseconds
     */
    private int asMilliseconds() {
        return (this.minutes*60+this.seconds)*1000+this.milliseconds;
    }

    /**
     * Obtain the result of adding this Time. to the given Time.
     */
    public Time add(Time other) {
        return new Time(this.asMilliseconds()+other.asMilliseconds());
    }

    /**
     * Obtain the result of dividing this Time by the given value.
     * The result is rounded to the nearest millisecond.
     */
    public Time divideBy(int value) { 
        return new Time((int)Math.round(this.asMilliseconds()/(double)value)); 
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the given object is a Time object and represents the same time value as this Time 
     * object, otherwise returns false.
     */

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Time)) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            Time other = (Time)o;
            return this.asMilliseconds()==other.asMilliseconds();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Obtain a hashcode value for this object.
     */
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.asMilliseconds();
    }

    /**
     * Compare this Time object with the other Time object, returning -1, 0 or 1, depending on whether this 
     * Time precedes, is equal to, or exceeds the other time value.
     * 
     */
    public int compareTo(Time other) {
        final int difference = this.asMilliseconds()-other.asMilliseconds();
        return difference==0 ? 0 : difference/Math.abs(difference);
    }

    /**
     * Obtain a String representation of this Time.
     */
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%03d", this.getMinutes(), this.getSeconds(), this.getMilliseconds());       
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem you faced.

Comment: I think your problem is this `time [x] = data[x].trim();`. You have to parse the String `data[x]` into your `Time` class. In a way like this: `time [x] = new Time(data[x].trim())`

Comment: Unfortunately the time class that was provided cannot be modified. The first driver takes in a String and array of Object Time as parameters. Right now I'm struggling to add the Strings into the Array.

Comment: @Blobonat i think there is no Time class constructor that accept input as String. You can use Time's `valueOf` but it only accept String for mat like `HH:mm:ss`. (In this case it is `mm:ss:SSS`) So i suggest you use `LocalTime` and parse it with `DateTimeFormatter` instead.

Comment: @Minh I suspect the `Time` class being used here is actually a custom one, notice the lack of an import statement for it.

Comment: @Minh I wasn't sure which Time class OP is using. For `java.time` the constructor is `Time(int hour, int minute, int second)`. So he has to split the input at `:` and parse it into Integer.

Comment: There's a constructor that takes in a string. The Time Class was provided and cannot be modified.

Comment: @Tia Can you please edit your question and add the constructor of `Time`?

Comment: Hi @Minh, yes the Time class is a custom one.

Comment: I've added the Time class

Comment: @Blobonat: Ah, sorry about my bad. @Tia: Since your Time class was revealed, and it got  `public Time(String string)` just following @Blobonat suggestion.

Comment: I have edited the constructor to:                                                              Time[]  time = new Time [data.length];  and I've also modified the loop to            for (int x = 1; x < data.length; x++)
  {
   time [x] = new Time(data[x].trim());
  } but that results in an empty array.

Comment: @Tia Try this:  `time [x - 1] = new Time(data[x].trim());`.

Comment: @Blobonat I still get a null array. I think the issue is with having new Time() in the loop but without it then I get a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Driver constructor should be fixed:

```
    public Driver(String dataLine) {
    String str = dataLine.substring(1, dataLine.length() - 1);
    String[] data = str.split(",");
    name = data[0].replace("(", "").trim();//remove "("
    time = new Time[data.length - 1];

    for (int x = 0; x < time.length; x++) {
        time[x] = new Time(data[x + 1].trim());
    }
    }
```

Also in the Time class constructor use scanner delimiter as:

```
scanner.useDelimiter(":|\"");
```

This is the final output:

*Hussein Suleman [02:40:010, 02:39:800]*